# Escaping PowerShell Special Characters

Tags: powershell, escaping

I have this PowerShell string:

```
"/qP9O7BayvZAoAqg5sTHzmHAQ3Ghv1E+mFkoYDa6tG8keQU2pzPYvpVE6i3MIT7e+k0QQafHpvFMFz2um7xTMQ=="
```

which I have escaped as follows:

```
"\/qP9O7BayvZAoAqg5sTHzmHAQ3Ghv1E\+mFkoYDa6tG8keQU2pzPYvpVE6i3MIT7e\+k0QQafHpvFMFz2um7xTMQ=="
```

But the string is not being acccepted. It's ok when pasted in `"`. Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: "Not being accepted" ... *where*? "OK when paste" ... *where*? For what purpose? Do you get an error? What does it say?

Comment: [regex]::Escape('cr.azy+str\ing')

Comment: Not being accepted - When I run the cmdkey below. Just never finished executing the script (Just says running script in the powershell console)
cmdkey /add:$StorageAccountPath /user:$StorageAccount /pass:$key. The key being the string I supplied originally. It's ok when I paste the same string into the Windows Credential Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in PowerShell *always* must be surrounded in either single or double quotes.  The difference between the two is whether or not you want to substitute variables.

Imagine this:

```
$name = 'Stephen'
Write-output "Hello $name"
Write-Output 'Hello $name'
```

The output of this would be the following:

```
Hello Stephen
Hello $name
```

Use double quotes when you want to substitute or expand variables, and use single-quotes when you want to present text exactly as you list it.

Comment: Thanks, I first tried single quote but I was unable to add the credential using cmdkey. When

Comment: I did try single quotes to start but it was ineffective failing to add the credential with cmdkey. I then tried escaping the forward slash with the backslash (below). The cmdkey worked but the credential is wrong (understand this would be due to the single quotes):  $StorageAccountPath = 'xxx'
$StorageAccount = 'xxx'
$Key = '\/qP9O7BayvZAoAqg5sTHzmHAQ3Ghv1E+mFkoYDa6tG8keQU2pzPYvpVE6i3MIT7e+k0QQafHpvFMFz2um7xTMQ=='
cmdkey /add:$StorageAccountPath /user:$StorageAccount /pass:$key   Hence I tried double quotes and escaping the special characters with no success on the original string.